# Overloading >> operator for dynamic c string class

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, cin, istream

I need to overloading the cin >> operator for my c string class. I have overloaded the operator before but don't understand how to do this dynamically without having the size before hand to create the c string.

This is for homework and I must not use the string class. I also have to use dynamic allocation.

This is what I have so far... I know it's probably very poorly written, forgive me I'm a beginner.

```
istream& operator>> (istream& is, MyString& s1) 
{   
    MyString temp;
    int size = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while (isspace(temp.data[i]) == true) {
        is.get(temp.data[i]);
        i++;
    }

    while (isspace(temp.data[j]) != true) {
        size++;
        temp.grow(size);
        is >> temp.data[j];
        j++;
    }

    return is;  
}
```

Comment: If your mystery `MyString` class supports appending a single char (and dynamically growing internally if needed), this should be simpler than you're making it.

Comment: @WhozCraig: considering that this example shows a `grow()` function being used, the string can grow dynamically. The real question is, what is `MyString::data` actually declared as, and what is it initially allocated as?  This example assumes that `data` is pre-allocated to some unknown size (otherwise the first `while` loop would crash).

Comment: I have a grow function that will grow the array dynamically. MyString::Data is declared as a pointer to the first element in the c string array. I guess I'm just confused because C strings require a length but I will not know that length until after the user is done inputting.

Comment: @user3422038: Since you don't know the length ahead of time, you would have to read characters from the `istream` one at a time in a loop, inserting them into your `data` buffer and growing it as needed, until a termination condition has been reached (whitespace, EOF, etc) to end the loop. That is exactly how the standard `>>` operators are implemented.

Comment: This code doesn't really make sense, you are reading all the spaces into `temp` and then you go back and overwrite those spaces with the non-spaces . Did you actually mean to discard the spaces? Also you never use `s1`.

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing exactly how your `MyString` class is implemented, we can only speculate about how best to implement streaming into it, but typically you should implement your custom `operator>>` something like this:

```
istream& operator>> (istream& is, MyString& str) 
{   
    istream::sentry s(is, false); // prepare the stream for input (flush output, skip leading whitespaces, error checking, etc)
    if (s) // is the stream ready?
    {
        // clear str as needed

        streamsize N = is.width();
        if (N == 0) N = ... ; // set to max size of str, or numeric_limits<size_t>::max()

        char ch;
        while (is.get(ch)) // while not EOF or failure
        {
            // append ch to str, growing its capacity as needed

            if (--N == 0) break; // max width reached?
            if (!is.peek(ch)) break; // EOF reached?
            if (isspace(ch, is.getloc()) break; // trailing whitespace detected?
        }
    }

    is.width(0); // reset effect of std::setw()
    return is;  
}
```

The STL's built-in `operator>>` implementation for `std::string` is a little bit more complicated (use of traits and facets, direct access to the `istream` read buffer, etc), but this is the jist of it, based on the following information from [CppReference.com](http://en.cppreference.com):

[operator<<,>>(std::basic_string)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt)

> ```
> template <class CharT, class Traits, class Allocator>
> std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>& 
>      operator>>(std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>& is, 
>                 std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator>& str);
> ```
>
> Behaves as an [FormattedInputFunction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/FormattedInputFunction). After constructing and checking the sentry object, which may skip leading whitespace, first clears str with `str.erase()`, then reads characters from is and appends them to str as if by `str.append(1, c)`, until one of the following conditions becomes true:
>  
>   - N characters are read, where N is is.width() if is.width() > 0, otherwise N is str.max_size()
>   - the end-of-file condition occurs in the stream is
>   - `std::isspace(c,is.getloc())` is true for the next character c in is (this whitespace character remains in the input stream).
>
> If no characters are extracted then `std::ios::failbit` is set on is, which may throw [std::ios_base::failure](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/failure).
>
> Finally, calls `os.width(0)` to cancel the effects of [std::setw](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw), if any.

Comment: Wow thanks for the in depth overload. I really only need a very basic version. Currently MyString has a pointer to the dynamically allocated array as well as the current length.

Comment: This is a beautifully written answer. Assuming the OP's string class supports `str.clear()` and `str.append(ch)` operations (the latter being the one I eluded to in general-comment, and the reason for my query), the fit should be *perfect* to fulfill the desired behavior. Really nice answer.